# Delphi 10.3.2 - Cannot resolve unit name System.Classes

Tags: delphi, delphi-ide

Brand new installation of Delphi 10.3.2

Error Insight reports errors 'Cannot resolve unit name' on core RTL and VCL units, like System.Classes

This pollutes the error insight report, and also blocks code completion (control+space) which is a real issue...)

What I have tried so far:

- Create a new VCL Form project: Same error, but project compiles without error
- Checked that Control+Enter open the source file: ok
- Checked that source folders are declared in the Browsing path (general Options)
- Added the source folders to the Library path (general Options)
- Installed IDE Fix Pack for delphi 10.3
- Uninstalled previous delphi versions (XE4 and 10.2)
- Cleaned the system PATH variable by removing references to previous delphi installations

I'm out of idea on how to fix this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Edit: When switching to Win64 platform, error insight errors are gone. So I tried to delete the Win32 platform, and re-create it:same errors happen again.

Edit2: I uninstalled and installed Delphi 10.3.2 again: The error is still there...

[image: IDE screenshot - New VCL project]

Comment: Error Insight is known for getting confused every so often and show false errors. We just got used to it over years.

Comment: Try to close an reopen the project. This will "reset" Error Insight.

Comment: @Kromster - now that the issue is resolved, error insight works perfectly on a big project (with delphi 10.3.2). The only exception is that it doesn't identify helper methods.

Answer (score -1):

Here's what I have done to resolve this issue:

- declare the bin directory of delphi in the Library path. same for bin64 folder
- clean up of runtime packages
- install all official patches for delphi 10.3.2 (when installed from iso)

Note that the first install was done with the online installer (so patches were not required)

I believe that the issue came from an incorrect library path, with bin and bin64 directories missing...